# Show short text when text is long?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show certain length of text inside element and apend dots if text is longer for example than 200 letters. Then append ... as link after modified text. When user clicks on those dots show full text. Excuse me my english is very poor.
HTML:

```
<div>
  <span="small2">TEXT MORE THEN 200 letters</span> <!-- Show 200 letters with dots as link -->
  <span="small2">TEXT LESS THEN 200 letters</span> <!-- Show full text without dots -->
</div>
```

My Jquery(not full because I am not pro):

```
$(".small2").each(function(){
    fulltext = $(this).text();
    if ($(this).text().length > 200) {
       $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 186));
       $(this).append('<a href="#">...</a>>');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not too clear what you are asking here... Where are you having problems with this code?

Comment: I am not pro bro. It shows string with certain length with `substr` function. I am asking u if u can navigate me to success.

Comment: What's not working with the solution you have?

Comment: @user3342042 no one demands that you're a "pro", but please try to describe which parts of your code are causing problems.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention my code is not complete in functionality. It should show short text with dots if text is longer than 200. If user click on those dots it should show long text if user click once again It should collapse this text back to short text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple jQuery implementation:

```
$(".small2").each(function () {
    text = $(this).text();
    if (text.length > 200) {
        $(this).html(text.substr(0, 186) + '<span class="elipsis">' + text.substr(186) + '</span><a class="elipsis" href="#">...</a>');
    }
});
$(".small2 > a.elipsis").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent '#' from being added to the url
    $(this).prev('span.elipsis').fadeToggle(500);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="small2">TEXT MORE THEN 200 letters TEXT MORE THEN 200 letters TEXT MORE THEN 200 letters TEXT MORE THEN 200 letters TEXT MORE THEN 200 letters TEXT MORE THEN 200 TEXT MORE THEN 200 TEXT MORE THEN 200 TEXT MORE THEN 200 TEXT MORE THEN 200</span> 
    <span class="small2">TEXT LESS THEN 200 letters</span> 
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KZ4TV/5/

Comment: Hi. Your fiddle seems static.

Comment: @user3342042 Click the `...` in the last line and the hidden text will be toggled.

Comment: Why text in your fiddle expand after dots ?

Comment: @user3342042 From your question: `When user clicks on those dots show full text.`

Comment: Yeah but those dots should be after long text if possible ?

Comment: @user3342042 1) I moved the `<span>` before the `<a>` and changed `.next` to `.prev`. 2) Typo. Removed.

Comment: I don' get this line of code: `$(this).html(text.substr(0, 186) + '<a class="elipsis" href="#">...</a><span class="elipsis">' + text.substr(187) + '</span>');` Can you please put comments or write to comment Why there are two same functions with different numbers ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3342042 `text.substr(0, 186)` inserts the text up through the 185th char, which is from your code. `text.substr(186)` inserts everything after the 185th char.

Comment: What is this ? I don't get it: `$(this).html(text.substr(0, 186) + '<span class="elipsis">' + text.substr(187) + '</span><a class="elipsis" href="#">...</a>');`

Comment: Thank you thumbs up for you.

Comment: I put Your code on my site: [link](testing3.ats-global.com/cz/cs/). You can check that It first display long text with those dots how to first show small text ?

Comment: Figured it out add `style=display:none;"` to that element

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is wrong, it should be like this:

```
<div>
  <span class="small2">qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm</span> <!-- Show 200 letters with dots as link -->
  <span class="small2">abcd</span> <!-- Show full text without dots -->
</div>
```

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/MXC5L/

Comment: Tried your fiddle bro. Without success. Thank you for post anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ID's** for both spans
Here is the CSS for the span
    #Span_ID

```
{
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 91px;
 }
```

here you can change width, which depends on the length of the text u want to show.

After this you have to include **mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js** file in your script tag. Because **text-overflow:ellipsis** won't work without this.

After this use [jQuery ToolTip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to show your complete text in the tooltip.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Bd3/1/) Example